# IOS Error: Google Maps does not load the map on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Google Maps does not load the map on iPhone. However when I connect the iPhone to Xcode and execute the project, it loads the map correctly.

This is my code:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.868, longitude: 151.2086, zoom: 14)
let mapViewtest = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)

let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = camera.target
marker.snippet = "Hello World"
//marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
marker.map = mapViewtest

view = mapViewtest
```

The console shows me this but I do not know if it has something to do with the issue:

> CoreData: annotation: Failed to load optimized model at path
>   '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/33FC89CC-DC52-4212-A361-F54DD2AC3CD9/App_name.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileProto.omo'

**EDIT**

The problem is that the map doesn't appear, but markers appear correctly

**Run app on Iphone connected to xcode**
[image]

**Run app whitout xcode**
[image]

Comment: Are you using constraints to size the map? You can do `mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.bounds, camera: camera)` and `mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]` which works just fine.

Comment: The map appear correctly with iphone connect to xcode, but when i remove the cable and run the app whitout xcode the map not appear @slickdaddy

Comment: When the phone is not plugged in and you see the tan screen, are you able to zoom out at all?

Comment: Yes, I can zoom out and also move around the map @slickdaddy

Comment: So the map still loads, just not to the current location, right? The map is zoomed all the way in to a coordinate that isn’t the devices current location.

Comment: It looks like this bug is reported in issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64504919

Comment: I added this line from @ slickdaddy,  mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] . Now it's showing map on simulator

Comment: Hi @AlbertoMier did you found the solution for this ??

Answer (score 1):

check your apikey again.

even if you use a wrong apikey, map will be show on a simulator, but doesn't work on device.